# Updating a set of estimated forecasts

Tags: estimation, forecasting, stochastic-processes, smoothing

Suppose I have some stochastic process $X_t$. At each time $t$, I receive an estimated probability distribution for $x_t$, followed by an observation $x_t$. After receiving a set of observations ${x_1, \ldots, x_n}$, I want to go back and re-estimate the probability distribution for each $x_t$, $1 \le t \le n$. What are some ways of doing this? Let's make the assumption that the estimated probability distributions are "pretty good", so that we do want to use the information they contain; what other assumptions do I need in order to make this an interesting/tractable problem?

For example, some (potentially totally misguided) thoughts I had were:

1. Suppose $X_t$ is a "first-order continuous" model: $x_t$ depends only on $x_{t-1}$, and if $x_{t-1}, x_{s-1}$ are fairly close, then the probability distributions for $x_t, x_s$ should also be fairly close. Then to revise my estimate of the probability distribution for $x_t$, I could use a kind of kernel density bootstrap sample and mix it with the original estimate: take all points $x_s$ such that $x_{s-1}$ is close to $x_{t-1}$, use these points $x_s$ in some weighted fashion to form a kernel density estimate $K$, and average $K$ with the original estimated probability distribution to get a new estimated probability distribution for $x_t$.
2. Suppose $X_t$ is a linear Gaussian model (so that it satisfies the assumptions of a standard Kalman filter). I could try forming a different kind of bootstrap sample: for each $x_t$, use a window around its estimated probability distribution to sample a new observation $x'_t$, and then use Kalman smoothing on the observations ${x'_t}$ to get a set of smoothed observations $\tilde{x_t}$. Use these bootstrap samples to generate new estimated probability distributions.

This is a mostly random question a friend asked me a while ago that I just thought of again, so I don't have a particular application (and hence why I don't have a concrete set of assumptions on the process).

Comment: this depends heavily how do you get estimated probability distribution. At the moment the questions in my opinion is too vague, although it is an interesting one.